# Slow response from computer engine in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I hope you are very well, I come to you because a problem arose that I could not solve, it turns out that I currently have a dedicated server (Hostinger Cloud) and a VPS with dedicated ip (Hostinger VPS) in the first service I have my PHP project, and in the VPS I have the database, I did it this way since the database is prone to scale in its weight and the hosting only gives me 6gb of DB storage, well in a few weeks it will expire my VPS plan and the renewal is really expensive, so I want to migrate to a Google Compute Engine instance.

I already have my Compute Engine instance, I also already configure my mysql server and in fact I can already access it from my system that I have in the hostinger cloud, the problem now is the performance of my system.

When I had the database hosted on the VPS when loading a datatable processed from the server, it gave me a loading time of approximately 120ms, and now with Compute Engine it takes 2.1 minutes to load the same table, the strange thing is that I have the Same configuration that I had in my Hostinger VPS.

VPS Hostinger Specifications:
vCPU: 1
RAM: 3GB
SSD: 20GB

Compute Engine Specifications
vCPU: 2
RAM: 4GB
SSD: 20GB

They both have Ubuntu 18.04, they are also in nearby areas, the VPS and Cloud Hostinger are in Charlotte, and the GCE instance is in Northern Virginia USA.

Hope you can help me with my performance issue. In the same way, thank you very much for reading me.

Comment: You can follow the performance [tips](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/how-tos/performance) for CloudSQL for MySQL. This document will help to improve the performance of your application running on GCE VM.

Comment: @Mahboob I've already read it friend, but even when I try to optimize it according to the recommendations, it still causes me that inconvenience.